# What if template argument explicitly specified to be function type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I tried the code below (https://godbolt.org/z/rcfPK451M)

```cpp
bool cmp1(int &a, int &b) { return a < b; }

template<typename T> struct S;
template<typename T> void test(T cmp) { 
    S<T> t;
    S<decltype(cmp)> s; 
}

void foo() {
    test<decltype(cmp1)>(cmp1);
}
```

And got the following compile error

```
<source>:5:10: error: 'S<bool(int&, int&)> t' has incomplete type
    5 |     S<T> t;
      |          ^
<source>:6:22: error: 'S<bool (*)(int&, int&)> s' has incomplete type
    6 |     S<decltype(cmp)> s;
      |                      ^
```

Which shows that `T` is the type `bool(int&, int&)` and `cmp` has the type `bool (*)(int&, int&)`.

I'm confused why they have different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a variable with that function type (the argument `cmp`), so the type decays into a function pointer type. You cannot have a variable with a function type, only a pointer to a function.

The [standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) says [temp.deduct]/3:

> After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type adjustments described in 8.3.5 are per-
> formed. [ Example: A parameter type of “void ()(const int, int[5])” becomes “void(*)(int,int*)”.
> — end example ]

In short, this decaying happens because the variable is a parameter to a function template, and it happens after type deduction. It does not happen if you try `decltype(cmp1) a = cmp1;`, because `decltype(cmp1) a` actually declares a function, no decaying needs to happen (and then you can't assign to a function).

In `test`, `T` is still the function type because you explicitly specify it with `decltype(cmp1)`. Remove this, letting template argument deduction happen, and you can see it gets deduced to the decayed type (since that's the actual type of the argument `cmp`).

It's the same as using `std::decay` (which is equivalent to `std::add_pointer` for function types):

```
S<std::decay_t<T>> t;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x1rbWM8o6)

Comment: I know there will be a funtion-to-pointer decay when passing a function as an argument. So actually, I originally supposed that there will be some compile error like `illegal initializer (only variables can be initialized)` just like when I write `decltype(cmp1) a = cmp1;`. I'm confused about when the decay you mentioned actually happened, and is there any reference in the standard?

Comment: @XuanInsr why won't you just find it yourself? https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.general#3.sentence-1 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#5.sentence-3